# Marginal Distribution in Beta-Binomial Model with Overdispersion Parameters

Tags: regression, probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, beta-binomial-distribution

**Problem Setting:**
We assume there is a sequence of binomial trials of size $N_i$, $Y_i$ is the number of events of interest, $x_i$ is the predictor associated with trial $i$, and $\pi_i$ is the proportion of the events of interest ($i = 1,2,...,n$). We know that this situation can be fitted by a **Beta-Binomial regression model with an overdispersion parameter** in case the data doesn't have binomial variance.

A **Beta-Binomial regression model with an overdispersion parameter** has the framework:
$$
P_i|\pi, \tau_i^2 \sim Beta(a_i, b_i), \quad \text{where} \quad \pi_i = \frac{a_i}{a_i + b_i} \quad \text{and} \quad \tau_i^{2} = \frac{1}{a_i + b_i + 1}
$$
$$
Y_i|P_i \sim Binomial(N_i, P_i)
$$
$$
\pi_i = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i}}}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i}}}, \quad \text{for} \quad i = 1,2,...,n
$$
**I am wondering how I can obtain the $E(P_i)$ and $Var(P_i)$ in terms of $\pi_i$ and $\tau_i^2$. Eventually, I can obtain the marginal mean and variance for $Y_i$.**

**Attempt:**
I notice that I can use the law of total expectation and the law of total variance to obtain the marginal mean and variance of $P_i$
$$
E(P_i) = E[E(P_i|\pi, \tau_i^2)] \quad \text{and} \quad Var(P_i) = E[Var(P_i|\pi, \tau_i^2)] + Var[E(P_i|\pi, \tau_i^2)]
$$
**But I don't know which parts I should put into the formula in terms of $\pi_i$ and $\tau_i^2$.** Does anyone help me to figure out it?

Comment: How does your model determine $\tau_i^2$. Is it estimated or fixed? Is it a function of $\pi_i$ and/or $x_i$?

Comment: I wonder why you are looking for the law of total expectation/variance. The $P_i$ is just beta distributed and you can directly compute the mean and variance for a given $x_i$ (from which you can calculate $\pi_i$ and $\tau_i^2$). What do you mean with $E(P_i)$, the expectation of $P_i$ for a given $x_i$ or the expectation of $P_i$ for a given distribution of $x_i$?

Comment: Thx @SextusEmpiricus, I noticed that $\pi_i$ and $\tau_i^2$ are not random variables and instead fixed constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using well known formulas for the mean and variance of a beta distributed random variable, in terms of $\pi_i$ and $\tau_i^2$,
$$
E(P_i)=\frac{a_i}{a_i+b_i}=\pi_i
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}P_i=\frac{a_ib_i}{(a_i+b_i)^2(a_i+b_i+1)}=\pi_i(1-\pi_i)\tau_i^2.
$$
Since $Y_i|P_i\sim \operatorname{bin}(N_i,P_i)$, using the law of total expectation,
$$
E(Y_i) = E E(Y_i|P_i) = EN_i P_i=N_i \pi_i
$$
and, using the law of total variance,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}Y_i&=\operatorname{Var}E(Y_i|P_i)+E\operatorname{Var}(Y_i|P_i)
\\&=\operatorname{Var}N_i P_i+E(N_i P_i(1-P_i))
\\&=N_i^2\pi_i(1-\pi_i)\tau_i^2+N_i[EP_i-(EP_i)^2-\operatorname{Var}P_i]
\\&=N_i^2\pi_i(1-\pi_i)\tau_i^2+N_i[\pi_i(1-\pi_i)-\pi_i(1-\pi_i)\tau_i^2]
\\&=(\tau_i^2 N_i + 1-\tau_i^2)N_i\pi_i(1-\pi_i).
\end{align}
As sanity checks, note that as $\tau_i^2$ tends to zero $\operatorname{Var} Y_i$ tends to the binomial variance.  Similarly, as $a_i$ and $b_i$ tends to zero, $\tau_i^2$ tends to one and $\operatorname{Var}Y_i$, as expected, tends to $N_i^2\pi_i(1-\pi_i)$, the variance of $N_i$ times a Bernoulli random variable.